# Jenkinsfile credential as paramter unable to use it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, groovy, credentials

I am trying to use the credentials parameter for a git clone.  But i am getting the error that the variables are not found

Param definition

```
  credentials (credentialType: 'Username with password', defaultValue: 'fcb2d7c3-4b35-4ef2-bdf0-24fc4ff1137c', description: 'Git credential', name: 'git_credential', required: true)
```

Usage in stage

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: params.git_credential, passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME')]) {
sh 'git reset --hard; git clone https://${DOCKER_USERNAME}:${DOCKER_PASSWORD}@repo_url/scm/${params.repository}.git --branch master'
```

> Error: Wrong variable used

Answer (score 1):

withCredentials publish environment variables, and in sh to access the environment variables, you have to do it like this: "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}".

Try this:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: params.git_credential, passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME')]) {
   sh 'git reset --hard; git clone https://${env.DOCKER_USERNAME}:${env.DOCKER_PASSWORD}@repo_url/scm/${params.repository}.git --branch master'
}
```